# How to find canonical form of three site MPS?

Tags: computational-physics, tensor-network

I am trying to implement the iTEBD algorithm for a certain model, where the hamiltonian acts on three successive sites. This means that my time-evolution operator is a rank 6 tensor, acting on a rank 5 tensor (3 physical dimensions and 2 bond dimensions). I would now like to decompose this tensor back into the canonical form by performing SVDs but I am not sure how to go about doing this. In the case of two sites, we reshape the tensor into a (2*D,2*D) matrix and do a SVD. How do we extend this to the three site case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the same way as before -- just that you first have to keep two legs blocked together and do the decomposition with respect to the third leg. Once this is done, you still have a tensor acting jointly on 2 physical spins, which you can decompose with another SVD.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by keeping two legs blocked together? As in, how would this translate into code? How would I go about blocking two legs and performing an SVD with respect to just the third?

Comment: Usually you have a rank-4 tensor where you do an SVD of 2 legs vs. 2 legs. Now you have a rank-5 tensor where you do an SVD of 2 legs vs. 3 legs.